# Problems with php include"" and web design or something like that

Tags: php, include

I have included two PHP files in page and between those two files made a lot of space .So are there any commands or functions that could help me to reduce space between files? I used iframe it worked, but when i opened recent posts with those frames looked awful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdP6q.png

```
code:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<head>

<div align=" left" >
<?PHP
include("nws.php");
include("post.php");
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this for vbulletin 4.x CMS page?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with PHP. Please post the complete (generated) code, as seen by the browser. Then we can look at why the layout is the way it is.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP and includes? (Nothing that's within <?php and ?> will appear in the HTML file unless it's explicitly output.)

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the resulting HTML that is generated, and fix as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying `float: left` to whatever elements the two 'files' are contained within on the rendered page, and adjust margins to suit.

That or include the latter file *first* (in the php script), and apply `float: right;` to the containing-element of *that* 'file.'

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots you linked to I am going to go out on a limb here and make a massive leap of assumption.

It looks like you are trying to create a PHP widget for vBulletin 4.x CMS, if I am wrong then don't bother reading on.

Your sample PHP includes head / html elements (malformed BTW) but these should not be included in the vBulletin widget.  vBulletin PHP Widgets should only output/contain elements that would normally exist within body, so something like this:

```
<h1>My Widget</h1>
<div align=" left" >
<?PHP
include("nws.php");
include("post.php");
?>
</div>
```

Having head/html in there is probably causing the vBulletin template renderers to fail.